# Is continuity over closed interval really needed for L'Hopital?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

It seems to be a commonplace that when laying down the conditions for L'Hopital's Rule it is stated that $f$ and $g$ need to be continuous on $[a..b]$ and differentiable on $(a..b)$.

For the record:

Let $\forall x \in (a..b): g'(x) \ne 0$ where $g'$ denotes the derivative of $g$ WRT $x$.

Let $f (a) = g (a) = 0$.

Then:
$$\lim_{x \mathop \to a^+} \frac {f (x)} {g (x)} = \lim_{x \mathop \to a^+} \frac {f'(x)} {g'(x)}$$

This is roughly how it is presented in (for example) Ken Binmore's *Mathematical Analysis* (1977), and he proves this using Cauchy's mean value theorem (solution to exercise $11.8 \ (3)$).

All very well till we note this corollary:

Suppose that $f (x) \to \infty$ and $g (x) \to \infty$ as $x \to a^+$.

Then:
$$\lim_{x \mathop \to a^+} \frac {f (x)} {g (x)} = \lim_{x \mathop \to a^+} \frac {f' (x)} {g'(x)}$$

provided that the second limit exists.

But of course here continuous on $[a..b]$ cannot hold, as $f(a) = g(a) = \infty$.

This result can be found in Abramowitz and Stegun's *Handbook of Mathematical Functions* (1964) in $3$: Elementary Analytic Methods: $3.4$ Limits, Maxima and Minima: Indeterminate Forms (L'Hospital's Rule): $3.4.1$

They don't bother with the continuity condition and just say that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on $(a..b)$, as is reasonable (if it goes to $\infty$ at the endpoints it can't be continuous there).

So the question is: in the statement of the main theorem, why is continuity on the closed interval specified? Is it not sufficient to request differentiability on the open interval?

Comment: You are right, continuity at $a$ is never required. For more details and proof look e.g. at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: I would say the closed interval condition for continuity is only for simplicity. A more general version in my opinion would be one-sided: i.e. $f (a+) = g (a+) = 0$, then do right-handed L'Hopital. For example, imagine two functions which are non-zero, continuous, and differentiable except for a hole of $0$ at the same place. Then by open-interval continuity and using the old $f (a) = g (a) = 0$ condition, it would seem L'Hopital's Rule is applicable. But you may get weird results if you try.

Comment: @TonyMathew What may be important is that if you don't specify continuity at the endpoints, a proof of L'Hopital does become somewhat more complicated, I believe, as you have to work on points arbitrarily close to the endpoint rather than just invoke the functions of the endpoint itself.

Comment: The conditions can be simplified further. Let $f(x), g(x) $ both tend to $0$ as $x\to a^+$ and further let $f'(x) /g'(x) \to L$ as $x\to a^+$ then $f(x) /g(x) \to L$ as well. $L$ can be $\pm\infty$. In general it is better to avoid redundant conditions.

Comment: Also the corollary you mention is more like this: if $|g(x)| \to\infty$ and $f'(x) /g'(x) \to L$ then $f(x) /g(x) \to L$ ($L$ can be $\pm\infty$ as well).